# How you can have a dynamic operation in vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Hello I have a method that modifies a state of vuex, the main function of the method is to add or subtract to a state of vuex.

```
setStep(state, type) {
    state.currentStep++;
}
```

But I need to pass the `--` o `++` to it dynamically, how can I achieve this?

I have tried as follows:

```
setStep(state, type = ++ or --) {
    state.currentStep[type];
}
```

But I don't get the result, any idea how I can do this dynamically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass a boolean instead of the operation and then use either an if statement

```
setStep(state, increment) {
    if (increment) {
        state.currentStep++;
    } else {
        state.currentStep--;
    }
}
```

or ternary

```
setStep(state, increment) {
    increment ? state.currentStep++ : state.currentStep--;
}
```

I should note, that this isn't the standard approach in Vuex. Mutations should always only have one side effect. You should have a mutation to decrement and a mutation to increment.

Then you can combine the two like in the above example using a dispatched method in your Vuex store.

You can also instead commit the step amount:

```
setStep(state, stepAmount) {
    state.currentStep += stepAmount
}
```

if step amount is a negative, it will decrement. If it is positive, it will increment.

Commits would look like this:

```
commit('setStep', -1);
commit('setStep', 5);
```

Comment: I had thought about this alternative, but can't you have it in a more dynamic way?

Comment: Yes I also have another idea one second

Comment: I like the option with ternary operators, the code looks cleaner in a single line

Comment: I agree :) Check the newest update. You can also commit the step amount instead :)

Answer (score -1):

You need to have two functions `increment` and `decrement` and you can choose to call either based on your requirement.

```js
const app = new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data() {
    return {
      step: 0
    }
  },
  methods: {
    updateStep(incrementor) {
      this.step += incrementor;
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <button @click="updateStep(-1)">--</button>
  <span>{{step}}</span>
  <button @click="updateStep(1)">++</button>
</div>
```

Comment: But if you only wish you had one, how could you achieve it?

Comment: Check my answer @JosuéMartínez

Comment: Thank you very much for help men

Comment: @JosuéMartínez you can have an incrementor which can be +- 1 or any other value

Comment: Your idea has worked for me without the need to condition my mutation